# Show and hide different divs on clicks on different buttons

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to show and hide different div's on click on different buttons. For example, when I click button "1", it shows the block with id="block-1". When I click on button "4", the block with id="block-4" shows and previous block #block-1 hides. I tried using different ID's because I don't know any other solution to show blocks with different content inside. Unfortunately, my current code doesn't work properly: it toggles the right class to show the div, but I can't hide the previous div or change the block once the button with number is clicked. On the default state, when the page is loaded, the first block (#block-1) should always be visible. Here's the link to codepen with the result: https://codepen.io/tomavl/pen/vYRLJVY

```
<div class="filter">
  <button class="filter-btn active" id="1">1</button>
  <button class="filter-btn" id="2">2</button>
  <button class="filter-btn" id="3">3</button>
  <button class="filter-btn" id="4">4</button>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="block-1 block-card active" id="block-1">Block 1</div>
  <div class="block-2 block-card" id="block-2">Block 2</div>
  <div class="block-3 block-card" id="block-3">Block 3</div>
  <div class="block-4 block-card" id="block-4">Block 4</div>
</div>
```

```
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.block-card {
  display: none;
}

.block-card.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```
var filterBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".filter-btn");
for (var i = 0; i < filterBtn.length; i++) {
  filterBtn[i].onclick = function () {
    if (this.classList) {
      for (var j = 0; j < filterBtn.length; j++) {
        filterBtn[j].classList.remove("active");
      }
      this.classList.add("active");
    } else {
      this.active += " " + active;
    }
  };
}

$("#2").on("click", function (e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    $(".block-2").addClass("active");
  } else {
    $(".block-2").removeClass("active");
  }
});

$("#3").on("click", function (e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    $(".block-3").addClass("active");
  } else {
    $(".block-3").removeClass("active");
  }
});

$("#4").on("click", function (e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    $(".block-4").addClass("active");
  } else {
    $(".block-4").removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

Comment: just show the one which clicked  and hide everything else . don't think abt previous!

Comment: @zod but the content inside all blocks is different and only one block should be visible. actually I tried to remove class that changes the visibility, but it didn't really help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you need with much less code by using common classes to group content by behaviour. You can use `data` attributes where required to store custom metadata in an element.

In the following example all buttons use the same event handler. The differences come simply from the `data` attribute on the button used to change the selector. The code just removes the `active` class from all relevant elements before applying it to the target.

```js
let $blocks = $('.block-card');

$('.filter-btn').on('click', e => {
  let $btn = $(e.target).addClass('active');
  $btn.siblings().removeClass('active');
  
  let selector = $btn.data('target');
  $blocks.removeClass('active').filter(selector).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.block-card {
  display: none;
}

.block-card.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter">
  <button class="filter-btn active" data-target="#block-1">1</button>
  <button class="filter-btn" data-target="#block-2">2</button>
  <button class="filter-btn" data-target="#block-3">3</button>
  <button class="filter-btn" data-target="#block-4">4</button>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="block-card active" id="block-1">Block 1</div>
  <div class="block-card" id="block-2">Block 2</div>
  <div class="block-card" id="block-3">Block 3</div>
  <div class="block-card" id="block-4">Block 4</div>
</div>
```